# How to get updated RSSI value from ble device in react native app

Tags: javascript, react-native

Hello I am working on react native app, in which I am using react-native-ble-manager (V 8.0.2) library. The library has readRSSI function which gives me current RSSI value. The problem is I am getting value from readRSSI only once (After I connect with device). After that readRSSI function will not give any value. So how can get updated RSSI value each time or is there any other way present for getting this value. Here is my method for fetching RSSI:

```
getRSSI(peripheral) 
  {
    BleManager.readRSSI(peripheral.id)
  .then((rssi) => {
    console.log("Current RSSI: " + rssi);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
  }
```

Thank you in advance!!!